# Rotate view on y,z axis simultaneously from one of it's End

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uianimation, catransform3d

Hi guys I am trying to rotate view on y,z axis I am successful with the following code but I want to rotate this on its end, now it is rotating from centre, I searched and I got `anchorPoint` property of layer to make it rotate but it makes unwanted translation of my view also it is not working

```
leftDoorView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0);

// Code to rotate view on Y axis and slight translate on Z-axis
 angle -= 1.57f;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            CATransform3D transloate = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, -(leftDoorView.frame.size.width/2.0));
            CATransform3D rotate = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 1, 0);
            CATransform3D mat = CATransform3DConcat(rotate, transloate);
            leftDoorView.layer.transform = CATransform3DPerspect(mat, CGPointMake(0, 0), 500);
        }];
```

For more Info I want to make Menu effect like Taasky app any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87268/3d-effect-taasky-swift) tutorial about Taasky menu can help. Especially the "Adding Perspective to Your Menu" section.

For further information about animations, there is also documentation provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html) and nice anchor point explanation by [David Ronnqvist](http://ronnqvi.st/about-the-anchorpoint/).